# Uploading a zip file to a server fails in Android

Tags: php, android

I have an Android Application where the user can generate a dump file of a SQLite table, zip, and upload it.

The dumping and zipping works. I am able to generate the zip file, extract it, and get the original dumped file.

However, the upload does not work.

Here is my code. I have a function that starts a Runnable, which starts the dump file, then the zip, then eventually arrives at the uploadFile function:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createDumpFile();
    }
}).start();


public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    Log.e(TAG, "uploading file");
    Log.e(TAG, "sourceFileUri = " + sourceFileUri);

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e(TAG, "Source File not exist :"
                + sourceFileUri);

        return 0;
    }
    else {
        try {

            Log.e(TAG, "file exists");

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL("http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/uploadToServer.php");

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.e(TAG, "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                Log.e(TAG, "Upload success!");

                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "result is = " + result.toString()); 
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

And here is the PHP code that receives the file:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "database/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

The response code returned is a 200, which most online guides assumed was a good enough metric to say that the file was uploaded. However, when I checked the "database" folder in my server using FileZilla, I saw that my file was NOT uploaded.

This prompted me to check the PHP's echo statement. Soon enough, I saw that the echo statement was "fail".

I have tried to look up other guides, but they generally were more or less the same, save for the String that's passed to the `uploadFile` function, and a handful updates to the mainUIThread.

Where did I go wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Code works. Just make sure that you have proper read write permissions on the folder where the file ends up in. Otherwise, you won't be able to write in it.

If you have ssh access to your server, one way to do this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/your/folder/here
```